# Parsing options having a common flag in C

Tags: c, getopts, getopt-long

I have a C program where I accept multiple arguments. Here, I have a common flag `d` for both data-store and disk. Is there a way that I can check for the flags in-order and get the value of `store` before I check with case `d`. I've tried various ways like adding a while loop before this to check for `s` and then enter this loop etc.

```
static void
ParseOptions(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int c, option_index;
   int ind = 0;

   while((c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "s:d:",
                          long_options, &option_index))!= -1) {
       ind = optind;
       switch(c) {
        case 's':
            optionStore = true;
            store = strdup(optarg);
            break;
        case 'd':
            if(strcmp(store,"datastore") == 0){
                printf("In datastore\n");
                datastore = strdup(optarg);
            }
            else if(strcmp(store,"disk") == 0){
                printf("In disk\n");
                disk = strdup(optarg);

            }            
            break;
        default:
            exit(-1);
       }
   }
}
```

Not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use getopt to process options in a certain order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473642/can-i-use-getopt-to-process-options-in-a-certain-order)

Comment: set a flag in the `case 's':` and test it in the `case 'd':` Note: there are **three** possible values for this flag, since `'s'` doesn't have to be present when `'d'` is seen.

Comment: Check the options for compatibility after you've finished parsing them all.

Comment: I faced a small issue with the solution @dasblinkenlight gave. When I provide the flags in the command line, I am not able to interchange the ordering of the flags. As of now i have to pass ```s``` after which if i pass ```d``` the code works fine. Otherwise, the code leads to an invalid option error and eventually segmentation fault. Is there a way i can avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store `optarg` returned for flag `d` in a temporary variable, and use it after the loop exits to set either `disk` or `datastore`:

```
char *temp_disk_or_datastore;
while((c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "s:d:",
                      long_options, &option_index))!= -1) {
    ind = optind;
    switch(c) {
        case 's':
            optionStore = true;
            store = strdup(optarg);
            break;
        case 'd':
            temp_disk_or_datastore = strdup(optarg);       
            break;
        default:
            exit(-1);
    }
}
if (store == NULL) {
    printf("Missing storage option");
    exit(-1);
}
if(strcmp(store,"datastore") == 0){
    printf("In datastore\n");
    datastore = temp_disk_or_datastore;
}
else if(strcmp(store,"disk") == 0){
    printf("In disk\n");
    disk = temp_disk_or_datastore;
}
```

Comment: I faced a small issue with this solution. When I provide the flags in the command line, I am not able to interchange the ordering of the flags. As of now i have to pass ```s``` after which if i pass ```d``` the code works fine. Otherwise, the code leads to an ```invalid option```  error and eventually ```segmentation fault```. Is there a way i can avoid this?

Comment: @nidHi I didn't realize `getopt_long` keeps state statically. I rewrote the answer to account for that.